# Нужна помощь с кроссбраузерностью

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток. В процессе создания сайта наткнулся на кучу проблем. Вот ссылка на сайт http://e-shop74.ru/dev/index.html
Когда заходишь через оперу то все нормально.
А когда заходишь через google chrome, либо firefox цвета у некоторых блоков теряются, в чем может быть дело?
Про IE вообще молчу.
И еще так же теряются отступы между блоками и фоновое изображение пропадает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <!-- Блок сайдбара с заголовком -->
```

Это такие коментарии можно писать в CSS файле?
Поменяйте все

```
    <!-- на /* и все --> на */
```

И будет у вас то что нужно. Валидатор CSS еще тоже надо было человеку сбросить:
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fe-shop74.ru%2Fdev%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=ru

Comment: ))Мой косяк, просто сначала я пишу css прямо в самом html файле. Спасибо, работает теперь как надо)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, устраните все ошибки, которые показывает [валидатор](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fe-shop74.ru%2Fdev%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: Все ошибки исправил